# Cuantas personas ven mis registros de firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic, angular, google-analytics

Desarrollo una app con [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase) y [ionic](/questions/tagged/ionic), actualmente tengo un objeto llamado publicaciones y me gustaría saber cuantos usuarios ven estas publicaciones en mi app

**`imagen publicaciones`**

---

[image: imagen publicaciones]

---

¿Existe algún método que me indique la cantidad de usuarios que interactúan con las publicaciones, o necesariamente necesito insertar esa información en mi base de datos de firebase?

A lo que he investigado estos últimos 2 días me indican que puedo utilizar google analytics pero no se como consultar esa información y mostrárselas a mis usuarios.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si, para métricas lo mejor es usar Google Analytics. Solo ten en cuenta que esa información es para uso interno y no se las vas a poder mostrar a los usuarios de la forma que tu quieres.

La otra solución es crear un campo en la base de datos (vistas) y actualizarlo(vistas++) cada vez que alguien vea ese articulo. Así puedes saber cuantas "vistas" ha tenido cada publicación y mostrárselo de una manera mas fácil a tus usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Como te respondi en stackoverflow en ingles, la unica forma de contar esos usuarios seria añadir un nodo en cada post que se llame por ejemplo `cantidadvistas` y adentro de el guardar de esta forma los usuarios que abren el post

```
lst_publications
  |____publication1
    |            |___ cantidadvistas 
    |                    |____userid = true
    |                    |____userid2 = true
    |                    |____.....
    |
    |___description
    |___empresa
    |.....
```

luego en cantidadvistas solo usas un `getChildrenCount()` y obtendrias la cantidad en Long de las personas que vieron ese post, de esa forma podes saber cuantos usuarios vieron algo.